# NoClassDefFoundError Websphere Applicatoin Server (WAS) ( o though class exists)

Tags: websphere, noclassdeffounderror

Good day he/she who might save me :

I have a application  which has to versions ( A/B) i configured a WAS in docker (using the Traditional image [[enter link description here][1](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/websphere-traditional/)](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/websphere-traditional/)).
I had the  WAS up and running for the version A of the project, version B holds some extra modules so i reused the same container ( that had worked for version A ). When deploying version B in was, i got a exception

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

And it tries to find a Connection file in the followoing package:

```
 com.project.base.utils.DbConnection
```

The problem here is that the class ACTUALLY is there, we have always had it there and it had worked like a charm, but in this container we have that exception (NoClassDefFoundError). We think it is a configuration issue but as said before, we have used a container that WORKS with version B.
And the diferences between the code is only more modules, not database files or connections.

I hope you guys have experienced something like that ( and solved it), if you know something to help solve this, my team would be really greatfull !

Edit 1 :

Stack trace i get in my webpage

```
Error 500: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: java.rmi.RemoteException: ; nested exception is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.caps.base.utils.DbConnection (initialization failure
```

That is the only stack trace i have access to.

There is another thing, some casting operations fail as well ( when the should not). To tackle this in the application configuration ( in WAS) in the `Class Loading and Refresh Detection` Section, i configured that the application should run with only ONE class loader, to avoid issues between multiple class loader, but the error continues to happen.

Comment: Is the class inside the application or in a shared library? This type of problem may require tracing (e.g. [ClassLoader tracing](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21196187)), so opening a support case is probably better than StackOverflow, but you can try to use the Class Loader Viewer inside the admin console to see if there are any potential problems in application packaging (e.g. parent first/last issues): https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/ttrb_classload_viewer.html

Comment: Hello, yes the class is inside the application and we have set the classloaders to be the same throught the application, this has been checked in debugging mode.

Comment: @kgibm, we have done what you said and configure the class loader as the guide said to parent last and sinle class loader for all .war files, and permutations of this options, still we have the exact same issue. Is there any other way of doing this or diagnosing the issue ?

Comment: Add full stacktrace with the error to the question. Also if possible try to recreate problem on the stand alone installation  (not Docker).

Comment: Stack would definitely be useful - if the failing load doesn't come through Class.forName(), then its stack will contain the loader(s) used for the failing load. For a class that's in the application but still not found, that often indicates a hierarchy issue (i.e. a server-level loader being used instead of an app-level one), and the stack could tell you if that's the case.

Comment: `RemoteException: ; nested exception is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` looks like your code calls some remote application, and that remote application does not have access to the required classes/libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved this, take a look
The project had a scaffold like this

ProjectCommon -> Comomn classes ( DBConnection was here)
ProjectEJB -> (DBConnection was used here)

There was a file that specified the link between this connection and it had a line that outlined this same connection between projects, so I just added to the server and everything started working, thank you so much for your suggestions !